# When trying to list pickled data I only get data that was last stored, how do I display all pickled data?

Tags: python, tkinter, pickle

I want to display all my pickled values in a list. However, when I run the program and press the button that takes me to the page where all the values will be displayed, I'm only shown a single value. This value is from the last time the program was run. When I close the program and try again it displays the value from my last attempt.

here's what I'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a3rT.jpg

This is the code where the pickling and display of data happens

```
class Streak():
    def __init__(self, action, streak_num, day, hour, minute, stored_streaks):
        self.action = action
        self.streak_num = streak_num
        self.day = day
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute


    def get_time(self):
        self.action = app.frames[PageOne].action_text.get()
        self.streak_num = int(app.frames[PageOne].streak_num_text.get())
        self.day = int(app.frames[PageOne].due_day.get())
        self.hour = int(app.frames[PageOne].due_hour.get())
        self.minute = int(app.frames[PageOne].due_minute.get())

        stored_streaks = {}

        total = (self.day * 86400) + (self.hour * 3600) + (self.minute * 60)

        streak_input = {"action": self.action , "streak_num": self.streak_num,
                        "total": total}

        store_streak = stored_streaks.update(streak_input.copy())

        with open("streak.pkl", "wb") as wpickle_file:
            pickle.dump(stored_streaks, wpickle_file)

        print(streak_input)
        app.show_frame(PageTwo)


    def read_file(self):

        with open("streak.pkl", "rb") as pickle_file:
            stored_streaks = pickle.load(pickle_file)

        #stored_streaks.update(streak_input) ## comeback to this
        return stored_streaks

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        streak_title = tk.Label(self, text="New Streak", font=XLARGE_FONT)
        streak_title.pack()

        action_label = tk.Label(self, text="Action", font=LARGE_FONT)
        action_label.pack(anchor="w", padx=30, pady=10)

        self.action_text = tk.Entry(self, width=250)
        self.action_text.pack(anchor="w", padx=30)

        streak_num_label = tk.Label(self, text="Streak #", font=LARGE_FONT)
        streak_num_label.pack(anchor="w", padx=30, pady=10)

        self.streak_num_text = tk.Entry(self, width=250)
        self.streak_num_text.pack(anchor="w", padx=30, pady=10)

        day_label = tk.Label(self, text="Day(s)")
        day_label.pack()
        self.due_day = tk.Entry(self)
        self.due_day.pack()

        hour_label = tk.Label(self, text="Hour(s)")
        hour_label.pack()
        self.due_hour = tk.Entry(self)
        self.due_hour.pack()

        minute_label = tk.Label(self, text="Minute(s)")
        minute_label.pack()
        self.due_minute = tk.Entry(self)
        self.due_minute.pack()

        get_time_btn = tk.Button(self, bg="medium purple", text="Add",
                                command=lambda: Streak.get_time(self))
        get_time_btn.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        test_label = tk.Label(self, text="TEST", font=XLARGE_FONT)
        test_label.pack()


        streak_list = Streak.read_file(self)

        action_list = streak_list.get("action", "none")

        display_list = [action_list]

        for action_list in display_list:
            list = tk.Button(self, bg="medium purple", text=action_list)
            list.pack()

        back_btn = tk.Button(self, bg="medium purple", text="BACK",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        back_btn.pack()
```

I included print so I could make sure that the get_time function was working. From the first image this was printed:

{'action': 'first', 'streak_num': 1, 'total': 120}

When I print streak_list it prints the data that was input before the program closed

Comment: Didn't you reset your stored_streaks every time when you call the get_time method?

Comment: Oh, is it because I have an empty dictionary?

Comment: Yes. Move the dictionary to __init__ and make it an attribute instead.

Comment: I moved it to __init__ of the Streak class and I still get the same problem

Comment: how do you create the instance of class `Streak`? Looks like its taking a couple arguments but your `get_time` method completely overwrites them.

Comment: @HenryYik I have a class called PageOne that has a button with the command: Streak.get_time(self).

Comment: Did you create an instance of class `Streak` or you just create it on your command in `PageOne`?

Comment: @HenryYik I'm not sure whether what I did is creating an instance. I've edited my question to show my PageOne class.

Comment: now it looks more obvious - you are creating a brand new instance of `Streak` class in your `command=lambda: Streak.get_time(self)` everytime.